# Is it possible to add a new piece of syntax to (for example) c++ with c++ code it self?

Tags: c++, c++11

Operator overloading made me think about this idea
(I know range based loops are supported in C++11):
I would like to make a range based loop like the one in python, in C++
(only for the sake of experimenting):

```
for i in range(4):
```

Is it possible with C++ code itself? If not, what must one do to accomplish that?

My goal is not performance or simplicity of the code, this is just for academic purposes.

Comment: If you want python syntax, write python code.

Comment: Why not just use `for (auto i : range(4))`?

Comment: That special case is actually doable. (In the sense @NathanOliver mentioned.)

Comment: Come on be a little curious.

Comment: You can have `for (auto &i: range(4))`, though. You'll have to write `range` yourself.

Comment: @spectras There are many other reasons for using C++ (have you ever heard about performance?)

Comment: @Baum But probably shouldn't be done.

Comment: @DYZ> if you want to write c++, use c++ syntax. The point works both ways.

Comment: @spectras The OP may want the performance of C++ and the convenience of Python `for` loop. There is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: You can make a preprocessor define for that, but this makes no sense. You make the code unnecessary confusing.

Comment: You may be able produce new syntax-like constructs with clever class and template design, but you cannot define new syntax arbitrarily. For example [`std::basic_iostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) uses the bit shift operators and produces a new stream-like "syntax" by using the operator in unexpected ways. However, you are limited to the operators, syntax and keywords of the language.

Comment: @DYZ> C++ loops offer the same convenience. `for (auto item : container)` is the same convenience as `for item in container:`. What he's looking for is how to write one language using another language. It's pretty much the same as asking how to write English using French grammar and vocabulary. That's nonsense.

Comment: If you redefine the language (using the preprocessor or by making some other pre-compiler or even by modifying the actual compiler to make your own language) then remember that no one else can really use your code. It will be a nightmare for others to read, understand and maintain. And with "others" I include the ***future you***. If you make such large changes in the basic syntax, then it's no longer C++. Actually, just straying even the slightest from the C++ standard specification (like introducing variable-length arrays) and you no longer have C++ but another new language.

Comment: @Hannes Hauptmann : note: such a `define` is a `macro` - terminology is important ;)

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily have to write `range` yourself - Boost for example already has it.  `for (auto i : boost::irange(0, 4)) { ... }`

Comment: To extend on @Nathan 's comment, I wrote a small function that comes very near for an implementation.

Comment: If you want to use a language where you can extend the language in arbitrary ways, you want lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, C++ is not extensible in the way you're describing. You can use the crude macros provided by the preprocessor to do simple token replacement, and you can use operator overloading to give existing pieces of syntax new meaning, but there's no facility for defining your own custom syntax.

If you want to do that, you can write your own preprocessor or write a compiler for your own language that produces C++ code (which is effectively the same thing).

Comment: _"No, C++ is not extensible in the way you're describing."_ Though one can come close to that syntax providing an appropriate `range()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The range example:

```
struct RangeStruct {
    RangeStruct(int max) : m_max(max) {}
    int m_max;
    struct iterator {
        iterator(int cur) : m_cur(cur) {}
        iterator& operator++() { ++m_cur; return *this; }
        friend bool operator==(const iterator& l, const iterator& r) {
            return l.m_cur == r.m_cur;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(const iterator& l, const iterator& r) {
            return !(l == r);
        }
        int& operator*() { return m_cur; }
        int m_cur;
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(0); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(m_max); }
};

RangeStruct range(int max) { return RangeStruct(max); }
```

Similar to python, you can write your own classes that "hook in" to the existing for loop syntax. Unfortunately it's rather verbose compared to python (there are libraries that help with that though). Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aef190fecd4decd1.